# ProgrammingError: relation does not exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, postgresql

I'm running into an error when I try to use psycopg2 to insert data in an existing table from a dataframe.

I've verified that:

- I can connect to the database
- The table exist and the schema is public
- I've granted all privileges to the user connecting to the database
- The table name in the script is the same as what's in the database
- I'm connecting to the correct database

Here's my dataframe:

| title | skills |
| --- | --- |
| Content Writer/Editor | Skills Creative Writing 5 years |
| Content Writer/Editor | Editing 4 years |

Here's my code:

```
def write_to_skills_table():
 cursor = conn.cursor()
 for index, row in skill_df.iterrows():
  cursor.execute("INSERT INTO skill VALUES (%s, %s)", row)

 conn.commit()
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit: Here is the full error message:

```
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-68-09d3a90be86a> in <module>()
    180 skill(p_tag)
    181 create_connection()
--> 182 write_to_skills_table()
    183 close_connection()

<ipython-input-68-09d3a90be86a> in write_to_skills_table()
    159 
    160   for index, row in skill_df.iterrows():
--> 161     cursor.execute("INSERT INTO skill VALUES (%s, %s)", row)
    162 
    163   conn.commit()

ProgrammingError: relation "skill" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO skill VALUES ('Content Writer/Editor', 'Skills C...
```

Comment: Are you sure the table name is the same, that in the database it is not mixed or upper case? What is the actual full error message? Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: I'm pretty certain the table names are the same. Here's how I created the table:

CREATE TABLE skill(
Title VARCHAR(100),
Skills VARCHAR(350)
)

Comment: In `psql` do `\d skill` and see what is returned. Have you tried schema qualifying the name: `public.skill`? At this point it down to the table is in schema that is not in the `search_path` or you are connecting to the wrong database.

Comment: It doesn't show up in psql when I execute \d skill. It's kinda odd because I can connect within SQL workbench and create a table that way. So I'm not sure why it isn't accessible?

Comment: If you are connected to correct database then probably [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) issue. In `psql` do `\d *.skill`, then `show search_path` and add results to your question.